# PHP XML how to set nodes and attributes to pascal casing

Tags: php, xml, dom, createelement, pascalcasing

I need to create a XML File with Pasca Casing style in PHP but when I create
for example the attribute: CustomerType  at the moment to save the xml the output string
convert the **CustomerType to customertype.**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
...
$element->setAttribute('CustomerType', "PROSPECT");
...
$dom->saveXML();
```

output this:

```
<cfdi:customer customertype="PROSPECT">
</cfdi:customer >
```

i need my output to this:

```
<cfdi:Customer CustomerType="PROSPECT" />
```

since the Customer no have no value y prefer eliminate the close node tag

```
</cfdi:Customer >
```

for this `/>.`

There is a way to config this  in php code libraries or setting parameter in the php objects?

I will apreciate your response. thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you use [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead? Its method saveXML (asXML) seems to output the nodes keeping the case you created them with.

Comment: Thanks in advance SimpleXml is working for me!!